# Change title in header

Tags: html

hey guys i have some problems.

I boughta finished template from ego studios . The problem that i have is that i cant change the title. At the title secetion in the head should be Guido Neuhaus, and it is written there but it wont change, there is alway ego stuidos.

could someone take a look at it. Is there any script which blocks it or something like that ?

```
 <head><title>Guido Neuhaus</title></head>
```

i dont know what to do.

[my website](http://guido-neuhaus.de/)

Comment: Please edit with steps you have taken. Better to offer code or a jsFiddle versus sending us to your site.

Answer (score 4):

it's in your javascript file: `http://guido-neuhaus.de/js/onepage.js`

```
document.title = 'Ego Studios' + ( targetSection.replace( /[_\-\#\!\.\/]/g, ' ' ));
```

Comment: yep, it shows up properly as Guido Neuhaus at first, then gets overwritten.